# Context-sensitive font-locking in emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, context-free-grammar, font-lock

Basically, I'm trying to syntax highlight the following piece of coffeescript code the way I want it. Explanation of the syntax of coffeescript functions can be found [here](http://coffeescript.org/#literals).

```
nameHere = (tstamp, moo, boo) ->
    ...
```

The names tstamp, moo and boo should be colored pink (and nothing else, not the commas and not the brackets) because they are parameters to a lambda function.

```
highOrderFun ((x) -> x * x) someList
```

Here it is the first x that is the parameter. Parameters can have default arguments:

```
class Foo
    meth: (msg = "Hello", bar = "foo") ->
        ....
```

Default arguments can be variables themselves:

```
defColor = "red"
print = (msg, color = defColor) ->
    ...
```

So `msg` and `color` above should be highlighted, but not `defColor`. An even trickier case is functions with default arguments that themselves are functions. I think that is to hard for emacs' font-lock to highlight correctly, but I'm including it anyway:

```
funTakingFuns = (f1 = ((a, b) -> a*b), f2 = ((c, d) -> c/d)) ->
    ...
```

This appears to be pretty complicated to achieve in emacs because you want the highlighting to be context sensitive. I've read up on the documentation on font-lock but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'd be grateful if someone could show me what to set `font-lock-defaults` to make it syntax highlight the way I want it.

**Update** Showing more coffeescript syntax examples.

Comment: I'm trying to make a dirty solution, so far I can make it work for when you open a file. For now, what is the major mode you are using with it?

Comment: Another question that I have is: do you only want this in cases where a `=` is used? What are other options? Also: Do you want it just for 3 arguments (for that the answer is below) or should it also be possible for more arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`font-lock-keywords` allows function values in the `MATCHER` field:

> where `MATCHER` can be either the regexp to search for, or the function name to
>   call to make the search (called with one argument, the limit of the search;
>   it should return non-`nil`, move point, and set `match-data` appropriately if
>   it succeeds; like `re-search-forward` would).

So we need to write a function that would search for the next function argument in the buffer.

Something like this:

```lisp
    (defun coffee-match-next-argument (limit)
      (let ((start (point)))
        ;; Look for the arrow.
        (when (re-search-forward ") *->" limit t)
          ;; Save the position of the closing paren.
          (let ((stop (point)))
            (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
            ;; Go to the opening paren.
            (goto-char (nth 1 (syntax-ppss)))
            ;; If we're before our initial position, go forward.
            ;; We don't want to find the same symbols again.
            (when (> start (point))
              (goto-char start))
            ;; Look for the next symbol until the arrow.
            (or (re-search-forward "\\((\\|,\\) *\\(\\(\\sw\\|_\\)+\\)" stop 'mv)
                (coffee-match-next-argument limit))))))
```

And the setup, to use with existing `coffee-mode`:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'coffee-mode
 '((coffee-match-next-argument 2 font-lock-variable-name-face)))
```

You can also use this in `font-lock-defaults`, of course.

This will likely use some other color than pink, but that's easy to change.

Comment: Why not simply define a new `font-lock-pink`?

Comment: Yes, sure. The author can define a `coffee-pink` using whatever variant of pink he wants (Emacs has ~20 named colors with the word "pink" in them), or use one of the existing faces. Like I said, that's the easy part.

Comment: Terrific! Is there also a way to fix so that the equal sign and value is not colorized when using default arguments? Also the function works somewhat haphazardly. When I open a coffeescript file, the styling is applied to the first function and the one below the point but no other functions are touched. It is not until I edit them that font-lock "realizes" that it should colorize them.

Comment: Sure. First, for some reason, coffee-mode doesn't modify the syntax table, so it thinks "=" is a symbol constituent. I think we only need to consider underscores as such, so we replace `\\s_` with `_`.

Comment: Second, that's a bug in the matching function, it stopped after the first arguments list it encountered. See the new edits.

Comment: Any way to get it to not highlight after the equal sign too? In `foo = (bar = boo) ->` it hightlights the words bar and boo, but only bar is a function parameter.

Comment: Note that while the funTakingFuns example looks fine with my current solution, it's a lucky coincidence, because `coffee-mode` already highlight targets of all assignments, with the same face that I chose. The match function above only finds arguments of the innermost functions, due to the "don't go back" principle. This is also solvable, but it would require a smarter traversal algorithm.

Comment: Great answer, I went a long time without knowing this was possible in font-lock.

Answer (score 2):

This is more kind of a hack, it's far from optimal (as I am not familiar at all with coffeescript), but perhaps with a little tweaking yourself, you can get this done.

All the ingredients are there.

The triggering of the commands/functions are based on the assumption that you use `coffee-mode`.
If you do not, this is not a big trouble, you'll just have to hook these things differently.

Put the following line in your `.emacs`:

`(eval-after-load 'coffee '(load "/PATH/custom-coffee-font-lock.el"))`

You can just save the below text as a file, and it will:

(1) Font lock when you trigger `coffee-mode`

(2) Font lock current line when you type the "`>`" as part of "->"

(3) Allow to font-lock the buffer by running `M-x coffee-init-font-lock`

```
;;;; custom-coffee-font-lock

;; Firstly, create a new font for this. 

(make-face 'font-lock-coffeescript-face)
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-coffeescript-face "pink")


;; Next, one function that should be ran after a file is identified as 
;; a coffeescript file. It will do the font-locking you want on 
;; the whole buffer. It is also possible to run it manually. 


(defun coffee-init-font-lock ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (goto-char 1)
    (while (search-forward-regexp "=.+->" nil t)
      (search-backward-regexp "(")
      (forward-char 1)
      (add-text-properties 
       (point) (- (search-forward-regexp "," nil nil) 1) 
       '(font-lock-face font-lock-coffeescript-face))
      (add-text-properties 
       (point)  (- (search-forward-regexp "," nil nil) 1) 
       '(font-lock-face font-lock-coffeescript-face))
      (add-text-properties 
       (point)  (- (search-forward-regexp ")" nil nil) 1) 
       '(font-lock-face font-lock-coffeescript-face))
      (move-end-of-line 1)))
  )

  ;; This actually runs that function.
  (coffee-init-font-lock)


;; This advice will be ran everytime you write something. It will check 
;; whether "->" is before it, so when you type the final ">", it will
;; do the font locking for the current line (it also checks for your mode).

(defadvice self-insert-command (after coffee-font-lock activate)
  (when (and (looking-back "->") (eq major-mode 'coffee-mode))
    (save-excursion 
        (search-backward-regexp "(")
        (forward-char 1)
        (add-text-properties 
         (point)  (- (search-forward-regexp "," nil nil) 1) 
         '(font-lock-face font-lock-coffeescript-face))
        (add-text-properties 
         (point)  (- (search-forward-regexp "," nil nil) 1) 
         '(font-lock-face font-lock-coffeescript-face))
        (add-text-properties 
         (point)  (- (search-forward-regexp ")" nil nil) 1) 
         '(font-lock-face font-lock-coffeescript-face))))
  )

(provide 'custom-coffee-font-lock)
;;; custom-coffee-font-lock.el
```

If you have any requests, let me know. Like I said, I do not use CoffeeScript, so this might throw huge errors your way. At the very least it should help with some basic ideas.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice attempt, but font-lock provides a better way to do this.

Comment: I would indeed say there is. I myself had looked for this functionality before, but could not find it. You did provide the answer.

Comment: Indeed, the doc for font-lock-keywords is rather dense. I didn't see it the first few times, too.